# JBoss POJO Object pooling

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0, pojo

I am using a POJO (Non-EJB) class inside my JBoss server and creating multiple instances of it. Will JBoss create an object pool and manage this resource or will it simple create as many objects as I instantiate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain Old Java Objects are "unmanaged" the container has no way to know that when you say "new" you don't really mean "new".

EJBs have managed life cycles, are trivial to implement. If you want pooling why not use one?

Comment: What I need is the container to manage the resource in a pool but I do not need any other container services like transaction etc. So, what if I deploy it as an EJB without any transaction support ? My lead says it will be too heavy to deploy the POJO as EJB. Is it true ?

Comment: You can specify that your EJB does not require transctions. But I don't agree that transaction support costs very much at all. With a single transactional resource the container's transaction manager should not get involved - when talking to a database you implicitly have a transaction anyway, the EJB extra should be trivial in comparison with real business work you are doing. If you don't use EJB you'll just roll your own pooling and pay a lot of the cost anyway.